# Trying to seamlessly join 2 div tags

Tags: html, css

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/NNMCV/

For some reason, I am getting a gray pixel where the 2 boxes join on the left side border.  How can this be corrected so it looks like 1 solid line?

Comment: What browser, I'm in FF 3.0 and not seeing it.

Comment: I don't see any problems in Chrome either

Comment: I'm using Chromium 9, and you've right, I don't see the problem in FF3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bumped .item_one up a pixel using `position:relative;` and it looked good.

```
.item_one
{
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-bottom:1px white solid;
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `border-bottom:none;` for `.item_one`:

http://jsfiddle.net/smPvH/8/

Answer (score 1):

The white dot is the bottom border of the .item_one div
set border-bottom:none; for .item_one
set top:39px; for .item_twenty

Also, try adding z-index:0; to .item_twenty to make sure that it is behind .item_one

Comment: there must be browser dependancies involved.  I see no black like.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding the problem, you could wrap the two in a "container" element as i did in [my update](http://jsfiddle.net/NNMCV/2/). Personally, I would probably use a definition list for this.